# Convert simple SQL group-by into LINQ to SQL

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, group-by

I'm having trouble. I can't understand existing answers to this on Stack Overflow and am too new to LINQ to SQL to be able to nut it out myself.

See this SQL:

```
select p.Name as ProductName, SUM(o.NumberOf) as TotalOrdered from [Order] o
  join [Product] p on o.ProductId = p.Id
  group by p.Name
```

Returns a nice 2-column table with product names on the left and the total number that product which have been ordered (across all orders) in the right column. How can I duplicate this in LINQ to SQL?

Here is what I've got so far:

```
var ctx = new DataClasses1DataContext();
var totalProducts = (from o in ctx.Orders
                     join p in ctx.Products on o.ProductId equals p.Id
                     select new { p.Name, o.NumberOf })
    .GroupBy(t => t.Name)
    .Select(g => g.Key, ... );
```

What goes at the ... ?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

It looks to me like you want:

```
.Select(g => new { ProductName = g.Key, TotalOrdered = g.Sum(x => x.NumberOf) })
```

You can do your whole query as either a single query expression or without using query expressions at all though:

```
var totalProducts = ctx.Orders
                       .Join(ctx.Products, o => o.ProductId, p => p.Id,
                             (o, p) => new { p.Name, o.NumberOf })
                       .GroupBy(t => t.Name,
                                pair => pair.Name, // Key selector
                                pair => pair.NumberOf, // Element selector
                                (key, numbers) => new { 
                                    ProductName = key,
                                    TotalOrdered = numbers.Sum()) 
                                });
```

Or:

```
var totalProdcuts = from o in ctx.Orders
                    join p in ctx.Products on o.ProductId equals p.Id
                    group o.NumberOf by p.Name into g
                    select new { ProductName = g.Key, TotalOrdered = g.Sum() };
```

Comment: This is correct. Have just checked. Thank you for helping me in my brain-dead moment.

Comment: @Lisa: Your SQL originally grouped by NumberOf as well... anyway, see my latest edit.

Comment: Thanks for quick response and how it is done properly without mixing syntaxes as I did -- I just got stuck. Nice to see it can be done entirely with either but a single query expression would be the choice for this task.

Comment: @JonSkeet , How would you write the same using lambda expression?

Comment: @BilalFazlani: Well for the grouping and selection part, just call `GroupBy`; the tricky bit is with the `Join` as well, which uses transparent identifiers. I would try to use query expressions for code like this - why do you particularly *want* to use a lambda expression here?

Comment: @JonSkeet Just a personal preference - They are easier to understand and to write... I see you have writen it using lambda expression too.

Comment: @BilalFazlani: Yes, it seems I have - and it looks *much* harder to understand and to write than the query expression. I use the lambda expression form when it's simple, and when there are no transparent identifiers - but as soon as it gets more complicated, query expressions really shine.

Comment: @JonSkeet I agree. I am starting to think that query expressions are more granular in nature and give you more control. (I am not sure though because I have never written any). This weekend I am going to devote to query expressions and find out :)

Comment: @BilalFazlani: They definitely don't give you more control - *anything* you can do in a query expression, you can do with lambda expressions, but the reverse is not true. What they give you is more readability, primarily because of transparent identifiers.

Answer (score 6):

```
TotalOrdered = g.Sum(o => o.NumberOf)
```

make use of above for .... than statement might be

```
   select new { ProductName=  g.Key, TotalOrdered  = g.Sum(o => o.NumberOf) };

var query = from o in ctx.Orders
            join p in ctx.Products on 
            o.ProductId equals p.Id
            group o by new { p.Name, o.NumberOf } into g
            select new { ProductName=  g.Key, TotalOrdered  = g.Sum(o => o.NumberOf) };
```

Comment: I understand how to obtain the sum. What was confusing me was how to get it into a projection.

Comment: Yes this also works perfectly. I think it was what I was looking for in the beginning. It's much more elegant than by mix of LINQ-to-SQL and Linq extensions.

Answer (score 1):

Just pasting this here in case it is helpful to know how this could be achieved through GroupJoin method:

```
var totalProducts = ctx.Products.GroupJoin(ctx.Orders,
    outerKeySelProduct => outerKeySelProduct.Id,
    innerKeySelOrder => innerKeySelOrder.ProductId,
    (outerKeySelProduct, innerKeySelOrder) => new
    {
        ProductName = outerKeySelProduct.Name,
        TotalOrdered = innerKeySelOrder.Select(n => n.NumberOf).Sum()
    });
```

Happy for it to be edited if it can be improved.