# Get click statistics count grouped by month

Tags: sql-server, linq

Been trying to find a proper solution, but have so far been unable to understand or find one properly.

Have the following DB:

[image]

I am trying to get the number of clicks in each month. 
So i would get something like:

```
--------------
January - 10
February - 7
March - 22
etc.
```

This is my code so far:

```
var MonthlyCount = from c in ClickStatistics
               group c.LogDate by new { date = c.LogDate, Id = c.ID }into grp
                    select new{
                        Month = grp.Key.date.Month,
                        Clicks = grp.Key.Id
                    };
```

But right now i am just getting this:

[image]

Comment: Have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6606405/convert-simple-sql-group-by-into-linq-to-sql

Comment: @Thomas seems pretty much what i have tried to do, but not quite right

Comment: Don't group by `c.ID` if you don't want seperate entries for each `c.ID` and to group the months together they must match in value, so `c.LogDate.Month` else you'll groups for each seperate time unit.

Comment: @STDMP, not sure how that would look ? when i try to do it as i think it is, it just displays the exact same thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Groups items together that have the same `c.LogDate.Month`. Selects the first item of the group to extract the month as text value (we grouped by month so they should all be equal in that regard) and counts the number of entries in the group.

```
var ClickStatistics = new List<Clicks>()
{
    new Clicks() { ID = 1, LogDate = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-1)},
    new Clicks() { ID = 2, LogDate = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-1)},
    new Clicks() { ID = 3, LogDate = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(0)},
    new Clicks() { ID = 4, LogDate = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(0)},
    new Clicks() { ID = 5, LogDate = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(1)},
};

var MonthlyCount = from c in ClickStatistics
                   group c by new { date = c.LogDate.Month } into grp
                   select new
                   {
                       Month = grp.First().LogDate.ToString("MMMM"),
                       Clicks = grp.Count(),
                   };
```

Comment: Without the tostring, it seems to work, almost as intended. Because when i add the tostring i get the following error: NotSupportedException: Method 'System.String ToString(System.String)' has no supported translation to SQL.

Comment: it might just be linqpad that does this.. I will try to add it to my code, and see if it will display the correct values. Will mark this as answer if so

Comment: @andrelange91 Try `Month = string.Format("{0:MMMM}", grp.First().LogDate)`